# Prove the converges of the followin sequence and find the limit

Tags: analysis

I wonder if anyone can solve the following problem for me:

The sequence of real numbers $x_n$ is defined inductively by
$$
x_1=4 \quad\text{and}\quad x_{n+1}=\frac4{x_n}+\frac{x_n}2.
$$
Show that $x_n$ converges and find its limit

Thanks to every one contribute in the solution.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the difference $x_{n+1}-x_n$:
$$x_{n+1}-x_n=\frac{8-x_n^2}{2x_n}$$
If you can show that $$x_{n+1}-x_n\le 0$$ for all $n$ then you know that $x_n$ is monotonic. If you can further show that $x_n$ is bounded (i.e. has a lower limit), then you have proved convergence. Since $x_n$ is always positive it is sufficient to consider the difference $x_n^2-8$:
$$x_n^2-8 = \left( \frac{4}{x_{n-1}} + \frac{x_{n-1}}{2} \right)^2 - 8 =
\left( \frac{4}{x_{n-1}} - \frac{x_{n-1}}{2} \right)^2 \ge 0$$
This proves two things at once:

1. $x_{n+1}-x_n \le 0,\quad$ i.e. $x_n$ is monotonically decreasing
2. $x_n \ge \sqrt{8}=2\sqrt{2},\quad$ i.e. $x_n$ has a lower limit

Now you can simply find the limit $c=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}x_n$ by solving

$$c = \frac{4}{c} + \frac{c}{2}$$
which gives $c=2\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Matt: Thanks very much Matt, but could you tell me how is x_n^2-8 = \left( \frac{4}{x_{n-1}} + \frac{x_{n-1}}{2} \right)^2 - 8 =
\left( \frac{4}{x_{n-1}} - \frac{x_{n-1}}{2} \right)^2 and how we know that
\left( \frac{4}{x_{n-1}} - \frac{x_{n-1}}{2} \right)^2 \ge 0

Comment: The equality is of the form $(a+b)^2-4ab = (a^2+2ab+b^2)-4ab = (a^2-2ab+b^2) = (a-b)^2$, and since we're dealing with real numbers, the squared expression $(\cdot)^2$ must always be non-negative.

Comment: Rewrite this as $$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{x_n^2-8}{2 x_n}$$ Then we see immediately that this is the recurrence generated by Newton's method for the roots of $$x^2-8=0.$$ With initial value $x_0=4$ the convergence goes to the positive root $2\sqrt{2}.$