# Is "monotonous" ever used as a synonym for "monotonic" in math?

Tags: terminology

I saw a few questions and answers recently that wrote "monotonous" instead of "monotonic."  Then I Googled and see a [ton of usages](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3amath.stackexchange.com%20%22monotonous%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a) of "monotonous" in M.SE instead of monotonic.

It occurred to me this might be a locale issue. Are there any locales that actually use "monotonous" for "monotonic" in English-language mathematics, or is this always wrong?

Comment: This seems to me to be always wrong.

Comment: Here are my two cents: in Italian the two words are homographic, but not homophonic. Namely, the words are "monòtona" for "monotonous" (feminine), and "monotòna" for "monotonic" (still feminine). They are usually written without accents, though.

Comment: @A.P. Yeah, I suspect a lot of the occurrences are translations, but I saw a few that seem like they are quotes. Perhaps they are just written as quotes but actually translations from the original quotes.

Comment: Something monotonic is quite monotonous, so I think it is fair enough. I wouldn't say using "monotonous" is wrong; I would rather say it is unconventional. Searching for "monotonous sequence" in Google Scholar gave me a couple published mathematical articles that use the term for example. Perhaps, saying "monotonically" is easier than saying "monotonously," that is why the former became more common. Now that I have used both words many times, both seem alien to me.

Comment: I don't agree that monotonic things are monotonous. :) the Cantor Function is monotonic, but I wouldn't call it monotonous. :)  Also, there are plenty of things which are monotonous which are not monotonic - the sine curve is monotonous, for example, in the sense of "boring the longer you view it."  @LordSoth

Comment: Since you corrected one of my answers where I incorrectly used 'monotonous' for 'monotonic' (cf. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359290/prove-the-converges-of-the-followin-sequence-and-find-the-limit/359302#359302) I checked many sources and it appeared that in a mathematical context it should always be 'monotonic'.

Comment: Yeah, I started back-correcting lots of old questions, until I saw a few that looked like quotes, and I stopped at those. No English Dictionary I've found allows "monotonous" for "monotonic," but I didn't search far, so I thought I'd ask here before continuing my purge of old M.SE posts. :) @Matt

Comment: In German it's *monoton* and it is often hard for us non-native speakers to guess which ending a Latin or Greek word will have in English. Moreover, the German word *monoton* has both meanings: monotonous and monotonic.

Comment: no                          ...................

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is always wrong. It is a clear error, which a native English-speaking mathematician would never commit.

Comment: Unless said mathematician was trying to make a feeble joke.

Comment: Thank you. I was beginning to lose my sanity...

Comment: @Leon: "monotone" is OK, but I think "monotonic" is more common (except in "The Monotone Convergence Theorem").