# Monotonous function or monotonic function

Tags: education

I am from a non-English speaking country. Should we say monotonous function or monotonic function?

Comment: *Monotonic*, definitely. *Monotone* is also fine. *Monotonous* in everyday usage means *boring*.

Comment: So I guess nobody will be interested in monotonous functions. ;-)

Comment: In Italian the difference is even worse. The difference is between the correct [*monotòne*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/monotono_res-91131e7b-0026-11de-9d89-0016357eee51/) and [*monòtone*](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/monotono/).  (0 letters difference, just the accent).

Comment: Just for completeness, see: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/365717/is-monotonous-ever-used-as-a-synonym-for-monotonic-in-math Apparently, the difference between monotonous and monotonic in some languages is minimal, and we see it often misused as "monotonous" here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That would be monotonic function. Monotonic is always used in relation to the function you are talking about.

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MonotonicFunction.html

Monotonic describes something this is unchanged or altered, such as the function in maths whereas Monotonous describes something lacking in variety and is usually used in reference to tone.

Comment: "Monotone" is also acceptable (though not mentioned in the question).

Answer (score 9):

"Monotonic" or "monotone", but not "monotonous" (boring).

Answer (score 2):

monotonic  for sure is to be used.  Monotonic functions are those functions which are either increasing or decreasing. They are such that for each specific value of  x   there is a unique  y(value of function) which does not repeat for any other x.