# A function is convex if and only if its gradient is monotone.

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, multivalued-functions

Let a convex $ U \subset_{op} \mathbb{R^n} , n \geq 2$, with the usual inner product. A function $F: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n} $ is *monotone*  if $ \langle F(x) - F(y), x-y \rangle \geq 0, \forall x,y \in \mathbb{R^n}.$

Let $f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ differentiable. Show that $f$ is convex $\iff \nabla f:U \rightarrow \mathbb{R^n}$ is monotone.

My attempt on the right implication: I already proved that if $f$ is convex and 2-differentiable then $f''(x) \geq 0$. But this exercise only says f is 1-differentiable.
Then I tried the following:
$f$ is convex $\iff \forall x,y \in U $ the function $\varphi:[0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, defined by $ \varphi(t) = f((1-t)x+ty)$ is convex. Then $\varphi'$ is non-decreasing, then $\nabla \varphi(x) \geq 0$... but I'm stucked here.

My attempt on the left implication:

$ |\nabla \varphi (x) - \nabla \varphi (y)|| x-y| \geq | \langle \nabla \varphi (x) - \nabla \varphi (y), x-y \rangle | \geq 0$

And so $ |\nabla \varphi (x) - \nabla \varphi (y)| \geq 0 $ then $\nabla \varphi $ is non-increasing and then (By an already proved Theorem)
 it is convex.

Can someone please verify what I did and give me a hint?

Thanks.

Comment: If you define $F$ only on $U$, then it is difficult to verify $\langle F(x) - F(y), x-y \rangle\ge 0$ for every $x,y\in\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: Did you mean  *isn't* difficult?

Comment: no. How do you compute $F(x)$ for $x\notin U$?

Comment: As much as I love the humor in the error, the term is _monotone_ or _monotonic_, not _monotonous_ :-) Convex functions are anything but monotonous!
https://math.stackexchange.com/q/365717/52878

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Equivalent definitions of convexity for $f\in\mathcal C^1(\mathbb R^n)$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3996183/equivalent-definitions-of-convexity-for-f-in-mathcal-c1-mathbb-rn)

Answer (score 4):

1) If $f$ is convex, then $$
 f(y)\geq f(x) + \nabla f(x)\cdot (y-x) $$

and $$ f(x)\geq f(y) +
 \nabla f(y)\cdot (x-y) $$

so that by adding $$ (y-x)\cdot( \nabla f(x) - \nabla f(y)) \leq 0
$$

2) Assume that $\nabla f$ is monotone : Define $A =\{ x| f(x)\leq
a\}$. If $A$ is not convex, then there are $x,\ y\in \partial A$
s.t. $$ \nabla f(x)\cdot (y-x),\ \nabla f(y)\cdot (x-y) >0 $$
Hence $$ (\nabla f(x) -\nabla f(y))\cdot (y-x) >0 $$

It is a contradiction.

Comment: I think this is not correct. You showed that $A$ has to be convex because of contradiction. But even all of the sublevel sets are convex doesn't  imply the function $f$ is convex.

Answer (score 2):

**Argument for why gradient monotonicity gives convexity:**

Suppose the gradient is monotone and fix any $x$, $y$. We can reparametrize $F$ to
$$
G(t) = F(x + t(y-x)).
$$
Then $G(0) =x, G(1)=y$. Moreover:
$$
G'(t) = \nabla F(x + t(y-x)) \cdot(y-x).
$$
Now, notice:
$$
[G'(t)-G'(0)]t = [\nabla F(x + t(y-x)) - \nabla F(x) ]\cdot[(x-t(y-x)) - x],
$$
and so monotonicity tells you that $G'(t)\geq G'(0)$.

Then we can write the following:
$$
G(1) = G(0)+ \int_0^1 G'(t)dt \geq G(0)+\int_0^1  G'(0) dt = G(0)+\nabla F(x) \cdot(y-x).
$$
This gives:
$$
F(y) = F(x) + \nabla F(x) \cdot(y-x).
$$
Since this holds for every $y$, $\nabla F(x)$ is a subgradient of $F$ at $x$. Since this argument also holds for every $x$, $F$ has a subgradient everywhere and so must be convex.