# if function is continuous and real she must be Inverse?

Tags: linear-algebra

$R=${$f:[0,1]-> \Bbb R$}
R is all the real and continuous functions from [0,1] to $R$,i want to check if there is a additive inverse number relative to +,so is it possible to say that $f(x)+f(x)^-=0\in R$?

---

Maybe I did not explain myself correctly,I'm trying to prove:
$R=${$f:[0,1]-> \Bbb R$}
(all the continuous and real function )is ring
So the first step is prove $(R,+)$ is abelian group
And that's why I have to prove $f(x)+fx)^-=0$
to get additive inverse number.

Comment: What about $f(x)^- = - f(x) $ ?

Comment: You need that the function is strictly monotonous.

Comment: @Wuestenfux: [monotonic](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/365717/1508).

Comment: You have given R (or $R$) two different meanings! This is careless, considering how many letters you have to choose from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact $(R,+)$ is abelian group.

First you should prove

$(i)\forall f,g\in R$, $f+g\in R$

Given $f,g\in R$ then $f+g:[0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ and since $f,g$ are real then the sum too is.Since $f,g$ are continuous the sum is continuous (is a easy result from calculus )
Then $f+g\in R$

$(ii)\forall f\in R \exists -f\in R:f+(-f)=0$

Given $f\in R$ exists $-f\in R$( because if $f$ is continuous then $-f$ is continuous)where $-f$ is such that
$f+(-f)=0$

$(iii)\text{Exists a function $h$ such that for every function $f\in R$, $f+h=f$} $

Since zero function is continous and real then we denote by $0$ the zero function
$0=0(x)$ is such that for any $f\in R$ $(f+0)(x)=f(x)+0=f(x)=f$

$(iv)\text{$\forall f,g\in R$, $f+g=g+f$}$

Since the set of functions under the sum is connmutative then
any subset too is. Since the set of continuous and real functions is a subset too is connmutative.

$(v) \forall f,g,h\in R, f+(g+h)=(f+g)+h$

It holds since the set of functions under the sum is connmutative and since $R$ is a subset then $R$ inherit that propery

Then $(R,+)$ is abelian group

Comment: I can tell that because the function is continuous and real is Injective and surjective?

Comment: @NFLX, you sound very confused. $f$ doesn't have to be injective _or_ surjective. Please try to express your question more clearly.

Comment: No. Doesn't exist an implication of continuous function  to injective or surjective

Comment: I think that was very helpful A function $f:A \to B$ is injective if for each pair $x,y$ in $A$ if $f(x)=f(y)$ then $x=y$.And a surjective if for each $y$ in $B$ there exists $x$ in $A$ such that $f(x)=y$

Comment: you're welcome I´m glad that it help you

Answer (score 0):

If you freeze $x$, $f(x),g(x),\cdots$ are reals and enjoy the properties of the Abelian group $\mathbb R,+$. These remain $\forall\,x$.

All you have to do is to prove closure, i.e. the sum of two continuous functions is a continuous function.